# Resources$NotFoundException, Recyclerview не видит разметку

Tags: recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android

Выводит ошибку   Resources$NotFoundException на 44 строчке holder.id.setText(record.getId());

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Record> records =  new ArrayList();


public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Rents> arrayList) {
    super();
    this.records= arrayList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.records_item, parent, false);

    return  new ViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Records record = records.get(position);
    Log.e("TEST",""+record.getId());

    holder.id.setText(record.getId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return records.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView id;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
         id = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.record_id);
     }
   }
 }
```

A это XML records_item

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/record_image"
android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/record_id"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/record_image"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/record_image"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  можете посмотреть, пожалуйста)

Comment: @cherry, не знаю почему, но уведомлений я не получал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У метода `TextView#setText()` есть несколько вариантов (перегрузок). Один из них принимает число типа `int` помеченного аннотацией `@StringRes`. Он нужен для назначения текста из строковых ресурсов приложения. Использовать его надо так:

```
textView.setText(R.string.app_name);
```

При этом этот метод (в этой его перегрузке) будет пытаться найти строковый ресурс по `ID` любого переданного ему числа. Именно это в вашем случае и произошло.

Вам надо в данном случае использовать иную перегрузку метода, принимающего строку `TextView#setText(String text)`, предварительно получив строку из числа как-то так, например:

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(record.getId()));
```